# Is proc invocation stored in the class variable threadsafe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety

If I store block in controller's class variable and then invoke it from instances, does it cause any problem with thread scopes?
Parameter which is passed to the block is local for each instance.

Here is code example:

```
class BlockExecutor
  def initialize(&block)
    self.instance_eval &block
  end
  def sub_block(&block)
    @block = block
  end
  def call(object)
    @block.call(object)
  end
end

module ClassDSL
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def define(&block)
      @executor = BlockExecutor.new &block
    end

    def execute_block(object)
      @executor.call(object)
    end
  end
end

class Controller
  include ClassDSL

  define do 
    sub_block do |object|
      # mutate object
    end
  end

  def run
    new_object = self.class.execute_block(object)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you forgot something like the following in your controller:

```
class Controller
  include ClassDSL
  extend ClassDSL::ClassMethods
  ...
end
```

or perhaps from within the ClassDSL module:

```
module ClassDSL
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  ..
end
```

That said, are you really talking about threads or just processes? With processes, you have no problems but as soon as you use threads to run actions, multiple threads would be sharing the @executor class-instance variable, so whenever you run the block stored in there, you would never know which thread was responsible for its definition.

So in the end, it depends on the code that you are executing within the blocks as well as on whether you mutate only locally scoped variables. Your 'object' seems to be local but might easily reference other objects outside the thread's scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Class methods are set by `ActiveSupport::Concern`. It uses internal module with name "ClassMethods" in order to do it.

I was talking about threads. I believe `BlockExecutor` instance variables will be defined only once, on code loading. 
I wonder if execution of shared block is technically the same operation as read of shared variable. 
Obviously, if we assume that internal code refers only to controller's local instance variables.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that Concern does this, thanks for the explanation.  I think, you should be fine then as long as you keep the block definitions out of the controller's instance code.